# Impossible to make connections through closed ports?

Tags: protocols, ports, ip, protection

If you have closed all your ports on your internet protocol, you cannot make a connection to that internet protocol.
So how do attackers (DoS or any other means that need a connection) make a connection, when even if you have not closed all your ports, your firewall seems it has.
I am saying this because when I port scan someone's internet protocol, the scanner see's no open ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoS attacks don't require any open ports on your side. They can just use all your bandwidth even if the ports are closed.

How?

The IP packet are sent from the attacker, and routed through several routers until it reaches your system. If the port is open, the connection succeeds. If not, your system can send back a "Port closed" message or simply drop the packet.

Either way, the packet has already travelled all the way to your system, clogging all the path along the way.

Answer (score 1):

If a port on the target machine is closed, it will either respond that the connection was refused or it will drop the packet silently. Ports being closed or "stealth" will not stop a DoS as the target will receive the packets whether it responds or not.

In some cases ports are entirely irrelevant (see [ping flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_flood), [smurf attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack)).